DPI-C error with "conflicting declaration of c function"
I'm working on an risc-v project and new to DPI-C mechanism.
I want to using cpp to realize the pmem_read & pmem_write function and export it into verilog.
This is the declaration.
// paddr.cpp
extern "C" void pmem_read(unsigned char re, uint32_t raddr, uint32_t mask, uint32_t *rword){...}

// Dcache.sv
import "DPI-C" function void pmem_read(input bit re, input int addr, input int mask, output int rword);

// main.cpp
#include <Vtop.h>
#include <paddr.h>
...

However, when using Verilator to compile them, I encounter an error which reports the declaration in Vtop.h is conflicting with the one in paddr.cpp.
But when using DPI-C, the declarations are just different, really don't know how to solve it.

you miiight have also problem that char is verilog's byte

I found I incorrectly add the Vtop.h in paddr.cpp  which is the cause that raises the confilict error.
After removing it, the code works fine.
